# Why is one of the HDMI inputs on my TCL TV labeled as 'PC' and how does it differ from other inputs?

Tags: hdmi, tv

I recently purchased a TCL TV and I noticed that it has multiple HDMI inputs. Interestingly, one of these inputs (HDMI2) is specifically labeled as 'PC'. I was wondering what makes this particular HDMI input different from the others.

Is there a specific reason why one HDMI input is labeled this way? Does it have any different settings or functionalities compared to the other HDMI ports? I'm keen to understand how to optimally use these ports.

[image]

I would appreciate any insights or explanations regarding this. Thank you in advance.

- The TV is [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08PFMN3CL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which is sold as a smart TV rather than a monitor.
- The graphics card I plug into the port (in case that helps) is  8GB NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3050 - HDMI, DP, LHR

Comment: It will handle the picture differently [exactly how, you'll have to find in the manual] Primary is it won't overscan. It will probably also handle colour & timings differently. It will probably also allow to you use a different set of defaults.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say "ARC"? Because HDMI2 is the HDMI connector with "ARC"

Comment: If its not wall mounted, a clear picture of the connections might help.

Comment: Based on your image, I would assume it means that a PC was detected on that port. My TVs say something similar about whatever port I have a PC plugged into. is that not the case?

Comment: @FrankThomas - as it happens - I've got an Fire stick connected to the one labelled 'PC' and my desktop to HDMI1 (I know some systems are sophisticated enough to read the input, this is not one of them...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a copy of the Manual (Unfortunately [a somewhat dodgy one](https://www.manua.ls/tcl/43p610/manual?p=5), since I can't find a PDF),

Port 1 is marked as ARC - this  is better for use with AV devices. This might be why the other port is marked as PC. No idea why the manual is showing *three* ports, but I'd assume your TV is marked similarly.

[image]

Comment: For completeness, ARC means audio return channel.

Comment: So what I think I'm reading is that 'PC' in this instance means 'without features' rather than 'with extra features' - that's interesting!